# Conditional Loop VBA Help, Confused

Tags: excel, vba

So the reason im asking this one is because im not sure why this code isn't working so im confused. This isn't a matter of me not knowing how to do something specific.

So there are some dates that are being "saved" in the range AK23:AL72. This code is supposed to be comparing the saved dates to the dates in the range K23:L72 and if any date in rows: 23,35,36,45,46,47 is different it prompts the user with the seen prompts in the MsgBox. If any other dates not in those specific rows is different it is supposed to prompt the user for notes via the InputBox. What it is doing is just prompting via the MsgBox for any different date. It does some other stuff too but that is all working correctly. I have no idea why the prompts are all screwy to be honest, been at this for about an hour or two.

I know the code is a bit brute force-ish but im pretty new at this.

```
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    For i = 0 To 49

    cRow = i + 23

        For j = 0 To 1

            If Sheets("Monthly Status").Cells(cRow, j + 11) <> Sheets("Monthly Status").Cells(cRow, j + 37) Then

                If cRow = 23 Or 35 Or 36 Or 45 Or 46 Or 47 Then

                    ans = MsgBox("You made a change to a critical deliverable date, do you want to continue?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion)

                    If ans = vbNo Then
                        MsgBox "You are not authorized to make this change!", vbCritical
                        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                        Sheets("Monthly Status").Cells(cRow, j + 37).Copy
                        Sheets("Monthly Status").Cells(cRow, j + 11).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                        Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    End If

                    If ans = vbYes Then
                        ans = MsgBox("Do you have Scope Change Aproval?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion)

                        If ans = vbNo Then
                            MsgBox "You are not authorized to make this change! Changes to critical dates will be rolled back.", vbCritical
                            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                            Sheets("Monthly Status").Cells(cRow, j + 37).Copy
                            Sheets("Monthly Status").Cells(cRow, j + 11).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                            Application.CutCopyMode = False
                        End If

                    End If

                Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                Sheets("Monthly Status").Range("K23:L72").Copy
                Sheets("Monthly Status").Range("AK23:AL72").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                Application.CutCopyMode = False

                Application.ScreenUpdating = True

                Else
                End If
            End If



            If Sheets("Monthly Status").Cells(cRow, j + 11) <> Sheets("Monthly Status").Cells(cRow, j + 37) Then

                Worksheets("Monthly Status Footnotes").Unprotect Password:="SCPV3"

                Worksheets("Monthly Status Footnotes").Cells(MSFFreeRow, "D").value = InputBox("You changed a date, you must enter revison notes!", "Notes")

                    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

                Worksheets("Monthly Status Footnotes").Protect Password:="SCPV3"

                    Sheets("Monthly Status").Range("K23:L72").Copy
                    Sheets("Monthly Status").Range("AK23:AL72").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False

                    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            End
            End If

        Next j
    Next i
```

Further Clarification:

Its very confusing to explain via written words. So I am checking all the cells in the range  K23:L72 and comparing them to the respective saved dates in AK23:AL72. Then if a date in K23:L72 is different from its corresponding date in  AK23:AL72 i need to check if that changed date is occurring in one of these rows: 23,35,36,45,46,47  if it is then i need to prompt the user with a series of questions, if the anser to both of the questions is yes then I save the sheet and save the new dates in AK23:AL72. If the answer to either question is no then the date that was changed needs to be replaced with the old coresponding date from the range AK23:AL72 and then the sheet is saved. If the date that was changed isnt in one of those rows but is still different I need to  prompt the user for notes and then save the sheet and then save the new dates in AK23:AL72. If nothing is different at all then the sheet should just save.

Comment: Can you explain what your `j` loop is supposed to be doing?

Comment: Comparing `Cells(row, 11) to Cells(row, 37)` and `Cells(row, 12) to Cells(row, 38)`, correct?

Comment: j loop is because there are 2 column here

Comment: Your 2 message boxes are confusing. How does the person actually make the change? It seems you revert changes back no matter what

Comment: It needs to be `If cRow = 23 Or  cRow = 35 'etc`. Select Case might be better here.

Comment: You are looping through a bunch of rows you do not need to it seems. I would get rid of the `If row = # or # or # ...` by adding an array that has all the rows you want to loop through. THen just loop through that array.

Comment: You may want to make something like a logical flow chart to make sure you have the order correct. Seeing this visually may help you build your logic. At the end, you seem to make the very change you have tried to undo

Comment: I tried to better explain what I am trying to do in words. Please see Further Clarification in the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think SJR already pointed out what needs to be done, but maybe you didn't notice it:

This if-statement `If cRow = 23 Or 35 Or 36 Or 45 Or 46 Or 47 Then` will always result in `true`, because `or` doesn't work this way.

In pseudocode, this basically translates to `If cRow = 23 or If 35 or If 36 or If 45` etc.. 
`If 35` and all the other numbers will always result into `true`. As SJR said, you need to change that to

`If cRow = 23 Or cRow = 35 Or cRow = 36 Or cRow = 45 Or cRow = 46 Or cRow = 47 Then`

Comment: I think you should write it at least as If (cRow = 23) Or (cRow = 35) Or (cRow = 36) Or (cRow = 45) Or (cRow = 46) Or (cRow = 47) Then. Otherwise, it's hard to read, and you have recall the rules of operator precedence in VBA, which may be too tedious, especially if you write code in other languages, too. I think the Select Case is the structure to use here.

Comment: I agree that Select Case is better here, but I was more focused on explaining why it didn't work in the original code.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a Select Case structure in this case because you want to compare a variable to many values:

```
Select Case cRow
Case 23, 35, 36, 45, 46, 47
    ' MsgBox
Case Else
    ' No MsgBox
End Select
```